# Is there an alternative to Push Notifications using native platforms (GCM, APNS...)?

Tags: android, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, mqtt

I am reading about alternatives to push notifications on mobile phones using Google platforms (GCM) and Apple platform (APNS), but I've found a lot of gateways which simplify the interface for the developers but afterall also use GCM, APNS, WMS....

I'd like a true alternative for delivering messages on mobiles and after the message is received, I wish to generate a internal Push over OS (not over a Cloud Platform).

I've read about MQTT to implement this lighweight communication. Is there another option or have you experienced using MQTT for this purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a opinion type question, not really what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: This is an architectural question, just different from those about if-else's. Down vote if you want to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can go services like Parse Pushnotification or UrbanAirship. They basically work on GCM For Android(support ios too but i am not sure on the details). These have very user-friendly interfaces and easy to implement in aps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I agree these are good platforms, but I have some quality and reliability requirements which GCM is not attending. That's why I need a new architectural approach for this functionality.